# Worldpay Gateway not redirecting to Customer Order screen on successful transaction

Tags: worldpay

I have live site with PayPal payment Gateway and works flawless. Problem appears when I want to use also WorldPay.
Payment is going throught but after payment browser is not redirecting to Order Summary Screen and order doesn't appear as placed order in CP.
I set up everything as stated in Craft Commerce doc. I really don't know what I can do else :(

Orders only appears in ACTIVE CARTwith status REDIRECT.
[image]

Another order is adding to the same order that's the problem to identify what has been bought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you testing from a local domain or on a remotely accessible server?

If it is a local domain then the return cannot work since Worldpay doesn't know where 'local' is.

If this is a remote server then:

1. Is the site turned 'on'? i.e. do you need to be logged in to view the front end
2. Do you have http auth in place (for instance to stop robots crawling a staging site).

If either of the above is true then it's likely that Worldpay can't get to the site.

Finally, do you have CSRF protection turned on? Try turning it off. If that solves the problem then you will need to bypass it in some way in order for Worldpay to work.

Comment: One issue solved!  Thank you. Turning off CSRF helped to put order placed. Another issue that after payment still not redirecting to summary screen. How to force it?

Comment: This problem is also solved. I had to enable shopper response. Dunno how I missed that...